# Fixed-size non-cryptographic hashing

Tags: haskell, hash

I want to generate `Int64` IDs from `Data.Text`s. They will be used as primary keys in a database.

I know there is `Data.Hashable` from the [hashable](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.14/hashable-1.2.4.0/Data-Hashable.html) package which looks very nice but unfortunately returns `Int`, which changes it's size depending on the platform.

Is there any well-known hashing package I am unable to find? Or can `Data.Hashable` actually be used in this case and I just don't understand why?

Comment: OT: are you sure that it's a good idea to use hashes as primary keys?

Comment: @Carsten: In this specific case - yes, makes programming easier with `persistent`. I could implement it differently but it's just a small tool writing to an SQLite db...

Comment: I wrote a package called `hashabler` that might suit your needs, but this question is OT

Comment: "[...] but if your question generally covers… a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" - There is nothing OT about this question.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with implementing FNV1A-64 yourself?  Edit: Nevermind, the above mentioned hashabler does output 64 bit hashes using FNV1a.  So... problem solved right?  You didn't respond to the first half of jberryman's comment!

Comment: @snøreven And just FYI "Some questions are still off-topic [...] Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic".  It's in a list of exceptions below the line you quoted.

Comment: @snøreven in case this remark is because of my comment: the "OT" there means that **my** comment is not exactly *on topic*